# How to install mapbox studio in ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu, mapbox

Can anyone give me a hand to install the Mapbox studio in Ubuntu 12.04? I have downloaded the zip file for Linux but cannot find any installation instructions there.

Comment: This [link](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/source/#careful-with-versions) has information about building from source. The document covers TileMill installation. Further down the page there is a section on "Source install on Ubuntu Linux". The other place I would check would be the software manager/center in Ubuntu as it may have an automated install.

Comment: If you don't get any luck getting an answer here, maybe post the question here [http://unix.stackexchange.com/](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unzipping the downloaded file, double-clicking the "atom" file finally worked.